# Reputation Update Bug

Tags: support, javascript

There seems to be a bug in the JavaScript. If you open Stack Overflow and leave it for a while, in an other tab you answer questions, you gain reputation and new privileges.

If you than return to the old page, where you left, your reputation will get updated when you click on your username to show your activities, and the info about the new privileges is shown, but not the drop down menu which usually appears when you click on your name.

If you click again, you will not see the drop down menu as well, you must reload the complete page.

I'm using Firefox 3.6.15 on Ubuntu

Comment: The corner case of corner cases.  This isn't a bug, unless SOP for AJAX is to be considered a bug.

Comment: I meant, that the popop does not appear anymore. And always the latest headline message is reloaded.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug, but should be expected behavior when you haven't refreshed the page.

Simply refresh the page.